# rest framework multiple unique querysets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a facets method which takes a search queryset what's the best way to get both of these outputs serialized in the django rest framework?

```
# This only works for results
class SearchResultsSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            'a': obj.a,
            'b': obj.b
        }
```

Goal Output:

```
{
    "count": 0,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/q=Cupertino",
    "previous": null,
    "results": []
    "facets": [] # <--- can't figure out how to get this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is trivial to achieve with an [api_view](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) but you loose the niceties built into a viewset, like pagination etc.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import permissions


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def my_custom_view(request):
    queryset = build_a_queryset(request.GET.get('q', ''))
    serialized_results = ResultsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    serialized_facets = FacetsSerializer(queryset, many=True)

    return Response({
        'results': serialized_results.data,
        'facets': serialized_facets.data,
        # need to paginate on your own here
    })
```